# How to undo a non recent commit on Git

Tags: git, branch, commit, head, revert

Suppose that I have in master this log :

---

- commit 6 (head)
- commit 5
- commit 4
- commit 3
- commit 2
- commit 1

---

And I want to undo commit 3 so that I will have this log :

---

- commit 6 (head)
- commit 5
- commit 4
- commit 2
- commit 1

---

If I do this with revert commit 3, I only have this in log :

---

- commit 3 (head)
- commit 2
- commit 1

---

And it's not what I want.

---

Is there any solution for this issue please ?

Comment: With revert commit it should make commit 7 (head) on top with reverting changes to commit 3?

Comment: I'd personally make a new branch at HEAD, reset the old branch to commit 2, then rebase new branch onto it. With this approach you _might_ run into conflicts (but that's expected).

Comment: @evolutionxbox if you can show me how to do this exactly,

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can make a new branch at head with git checkout new_branch, then ?

Comment: No need. Use `git branch <new-branch>` to create the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `rebase --onto`. See an example:

```
$ git init
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ git commit -ma
$ touch b
$ git add b
$ git commit -mb
$ touch c
$ git add c
$ git commit -mc
$ git log
commit 849a63d70fee06aaa0022a1070071f5ac1ec7263 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Arkadiusz Drabczyk <adrabczyk@bigcorp.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 5 12:37:21 2018 +0200

    c

commit 43a6c0fa3959d1da88b89ab91dc29de1b5fb498e
Author: Arkadiusz Drabczyk <adrabczyk@bigcorp.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 5 12:37:16 2018 +0200

    b

commit 61d6d5fd8b0bca01acae2864b5175f01c156d860
Author: Arkadiusz Drabczyk <adrabczyk@bigcorp.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 5 12:37:11 2018 +0200

    a
```

We want to remove `b`:

```
$ git rebase -p --onto 43a6c0fa3959d1da88b89ab91dc29de1b5fb498e^ 43a6c0fa3959d1da88b89ab91dc29de1b5fb498e
$ git log
commit 88ea4078b221d7a5febf7cefefab789d97db86d8
Author: Arkadiusz Drabczyk <adrabczyk@bigcorp.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 5 12:37:21 2018 +0200

    c

commit 61d6d5fd8b0bca01acae2864b5175f01c156d860
Author: Arkadiusz Drabczyk <adrabczyk@bigcorp.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 5 12:37:11 2018 +0200

    a
```